# Dynamic compiler path in c_cpp_properties.json VSCode settings file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, embedded

I have a `c_cpp_properties.json` in my `.vscode` folder, and it's working properly. However, there is a line in it that is system specific:

```
"compilerPath": "~/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc"
```

And while I can assume default install for the `.espressif` tools, unfortunately the distributor of the toolchain changes the path on every version (I.e. `.../esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/...`)

I'm wondering if there's a way to use something like

`which xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc`

in the json so this will update with the toolchain updates?

Comment: Are you using the IDF extension?

Comment: You don't get symbolic links (or similar) in a common "bin" directory? If you don't get that, then it's likely the compiler won't be in the `PATH` anyway, which means `which` won't be able to find it anyway.

Comment: create a symbolic link to a directory of the compiler, update the symlink after each update of the compiler

Comment: I don't think VSCode will search for you compiler for you, that's why the json setting exists.  You could write a shell script to update the json each time you reinstall the compiler, but I think rioV8's suggestion of having fixed json and a symlink is better.

Comment: I think I have an idea on how to achieve what you wish to do. I will answer this once I'm at a computer.

Comment: if you have  installed 5 versions of your compiler, which compiler must the `which xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc` command return when you want to try if 2 versions back it was working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by mentioning that the most easiest way to do this is via the creation / or update of a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` as rioV8 mentioned in the comments.

The command `which xyz` will look through the `path` environment variable anyway, so unless you have a symbolic link under one of the paths listed in `path`, it won't be as easy.

That being said I can imagine that you may want to (for some specific reason) switch the compiler from time to time (for example when debugging historic versions) and for example you do this by having predefined environments where you specify the path.

So to do this I looked into how VS Code's CMake Tools parse the `c_cpp_properties.json` file and passing anything other than a string to `compilerPath` doesn't look like a good idea, however if we take a look at [Lines 430-451 of this file.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/896f499b99a85e60b36bd8b8bf5a5e779af14236/src/cpptools.ts#L430-L451) We can see what has priority when deciding which `CXX / C` compiler to use.

Based on that - what you can do is go to your `CMakeLists.txt` file and before you define the project you can add this snippet for your own CXX search:

```
execute_process(COMMAND your_script_or_command_to_get_cxx_path_here RESULT_VARIABLE which_cxx OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${which_cxx})

project(TEST)

#... rest of your CMakeLists.txt
```

For example:

```
execute_process(COMMAND which g++ RESULT_VARIABLE which_cxx OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

After you clean and generate a new build folder, it should override whatever is in `c_cpp_properties.json`

**But in all honesty, I would just stick to the symbolic link.**

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! what a great answer. I believe I have it working using this method, which for my use case, is definitely preferable